# Where is the Library?

Tags: macos, application-loader

I have a dummy question because I nothing understand in OSX.

I use Visual Studio for Windows and build Xamarin iOS app. Visual Studio uses Mac as build server. After the build process I need to upload *.ipa file to iTunesConnect through ApplicationLoader on OSX. And I encountered a problem, I cannot find my file from ApplicationLoader.

I found that file is placed in 'Untitled/Users/alexey/Library/...etc'. But I haven't see Library folder. What does it mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In macOS the `Library` folder of the user domain is hidden by default.

To show it temporarily

- In Finder open the `Go` menu and press the <kbd>⌥</kbd>(option)-key. Choose the `Library` menu item.
- In Finder press <kbd>⇧⌘G</kbd>, type `~/Library` and press <kbd>return</kbd>

To show it permanently

- Select your home folder, press <kbd>⌘J</kbd> to show the View Options and check the checkbox at the bottom.

  [image]